# Authorization header not being sent when using fetch

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

When I try and set the Authorzation header as below the header doesn't get sent to the server for the request. What's the correct way to set the Authorization header with fetch?

```
let options = { 
  method: 'GET', 
  headers: new Headers({ 
    Authorization: 'Bearer ...' 
  }) 
};
fetch('/api/somedata', options).then(function(response) { console.log(response); };
```

**Edit**

In chrome developer tools on the network tab I get this for the request:

```
GET /api/somedata HTTP/1.1
Host: someserver.azurewebsites.net
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/somedata
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Note there's no Authorization header being set.

And the server responds:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 61
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Date: Thu, 29 Sep 2016 03:16:15 GMT
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem; I tested using the same code as you posted and the `Authorization` header is indeed sent to the server...

Comment: The `Authorization` header does not appear on the list of [forbidden header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name), so there's no reason why it shouldn't work. Are you *sure* the requests are sent without the Authorization header? If you're using Chrome or Firefox, you can view request headers by opening the developer console with F12, and finding your fetch request under the "Network" tab. If it's there, there's probably a problem on the server side.

Comment: Yes I'm sure its not setting the Authorization header.

Comment: is it a CORS request?

Comment: Yes, a cors request. The server responds with a duplicate header for Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * when I use soapui, and doesn't work in postman either. So most likely the server. It's confusing though because I don't see why fetch isn't sending the header?

Comment: Have you tried using a plain object for the headers instead of wrapping it in `new Headers(...)`? I doubt that's the problem but it might be worth a shot..

Comment: Probably not the real issue, but shouldn't the Authorization header start with `Bearer`, not `bearer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your server needs to include the following response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

Comment: Did this resolve the issue?  I have the same problem but adding this did not help me.  My question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900977/custom-request-headers-not-being-sent-with-a-javascript-fetch-request