# Reactjs fetch with credentials doesn't seem to work

Tags: reactjs, authorization, fetch, bearer-token

I'm trying to do a GET request with a Bearer key and can't figure why it's not working.
In Postman, the GET request works perfectly, but in my React.js app can't make it happen. I get a 401 Unauthorized error in console log. I added the `mode: 'no-cors'` because otherwise I have a `Failed to fetch` error.

```
const token = 'https://website.com'
const key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
const obj = {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + key,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      orders: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(token, obj)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result)
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          orders: result.order
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error)
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error
        });
      }
    )
  }

  render () {
    const { error, isLoaded, orders } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          {orders.order.number}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This is how the object should look like.
[Postman GET response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vzxo.png)

This is the console log errors I get. [Console log errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pEto.png)

Without the `mode: 'no-cors'` I get this problem, how can I solve it? [Failed to fetch error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M48e.png)

Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: can you pls provide more details like where are you getting the value of the "key" in 'Bearer ' + key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authorization header not being sent when using fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760659/authorization-header-not-being-sent-when-using-fetch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could resolve it by simply taking out `mode: 'no-cors'` and `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`. So the object sent in fetch will end up like this:

```
const obj = {
  method: 'GET',
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + key,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use no-cors mode, the browser will not send headers that are not on the CORS safe list. Therefore, the "authorization" header will not be sent, and the server will not receive it and respond to the 401 code.

Here are more details. [Using fetch API with mode: 'no-cors', can’t set request headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44987520/6021280)

Solution: Remove mode: no-cors, and the server responds to the cors request.  Or just keep the content-type header.

Comment: The problem is I get a `Failed to fetch` error if I don't use the `no-cors` mode, or how else can I solve it?